# Sort the menus in json by rank

Tags: python, json

I have json structure of UI menus, what I'm trying to do is when user from UI enters new node or modify the rank node of any parent or child menu, json structure should get sorted out by rank node value.
Issue I'm facing is my sorting method is working until the rank value is in single digit once it get in double digit like 10, 11, 12.... 99, sorting not working as intended and menu is not getting on correct place as per sort.

**Sample menu structure for reference:**

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
             "rank": "1",
                "child":[
                        {
                            "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                            "path":"resouce1",
                            "rank":"1"
                         },
                    
                        {"node":"Admin.resouce2",
                            "path": "oath",
                            "rank":"2"
                        }
                       ]
            },
            {
                "node":"Workspace",
                "path": "wsp",
                "rank":"2",
                "child":[{
                        "node": "Workspace.system1",
                        "path":"sys1",
                        "rank": "1"
                    
                    },
                    {
                        "node": "Workspace.system2",
                        "path":"sys2",
                        "rank": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }

        
    ]
}
```

**Code I tried: **

```
config['menu-config'] = sorted(config['menu-config'], key=lambda x: int(x.get('rank', float('inf'))))
```

Maximum rank in parent or child we can have is 1-99.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your structure and sort child nodes, not the top-level ones you try to deal with currently which is pretty futile as there's even no `rank` field in top-level nodes.. Something like this (I slightly trimmed your menu structure, removing irrelevant fields):

```
import json

menu_json = {
    "menustructure": [{
            "node":"Admin",
            "rank": "4",
            "child":[
                { "rank":"4" },
                { "rank":"2" },
                { "rank":"3" },
                { "rank":"1" },
            ]}, {
            "node":"Workspace",
            "rank": "1",
            "child":[
                { "rank": "2" },
                { "rank": "4" },
                { "rank": "1" },
            ]
        }
    ]
}

# separated sorting lambda for reuse
rank_sorter = lambda x: int(x.get('rank', 99))

# sort top-level nodes
sorted_menu = sorted(menu_json['menustructure'], key=rank_sorter)
# sort nested nodes
for menu_item in sorted_menu:
  if 'child' in menu_item:
     menu_item['child'] = sorted(menu_item['child'], key=rank_sorter)
sorted_menu = {'menustructure': sorted_menu}

print(json.dumps(sorted_menu, indent=4))
```

would yield

```
[
  {
    "node": "Workspace",
    "rank": "1",
    "child": [
      {
        "rank": "1"
      },
      {
        "rank": "2"
      },
      {
        "rank": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "node": "Admin",
    "rank": "4",
    "child": [
      {
        "rank": "1"
      },
      {
        "rank": "2"
      },
      {
        "rank": "3"
      },
      {
        "rank": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: will this work for parent nodes also or just child node? because parent nodes also have rank node, modified json for reference.

Comment: Yes, but not out of the box. I need to sort root nodes separately. I updated the answer to cover that. For more nested structure you might want to go for recursive approach perhaps but that's left for you to try if needed.